# How to proof the derivative is continuous

Tags: calculus, rolles-theorem

Q) Consider a function $f:(0,1) \to \mathbb{R}$, continuous annd differentiable. $(\alpha_n)^\infty_1$ be a sequence of roots of $f$ which converges to $\alpha \in (0,1)$. Prove that $f'(\alpha)=0$.

> *Here I am using Rolle's Theorem get a sequence $(c_n)_1^\infty$ such that $f'(c_n)=0$ and $Lt \, c_n=\alpha$. But after this I am not being able to prove that $f'(x)$ is continuous so that I can use the sequential criteria.*

Comment: Suppose $f'(\alpha) \ne 0$, what does that say about $f$ near $\alpha$? No continuity needed.

Comment: @copper.hat could you please elaborate?

Comment: Another approach, assuming that $\alpha_n \ne \alpha$, $f'(\alpha) = \lim_n {f(\alpha_n) - f(\alpha) \over \alpha_n - \alpha}$.

Comment: The derivative is a function.  You prove that the derivative is continuous at a specific point the same way that you prove that any other function is continuous at a specific point.  That is, you prove that as $~x \to a,~$ you have that $~f(x)~$ converges to a limit $~L,~$ and that $~L = f(a).$

Comment: What @copper.hat said is the way to go.

Comment: @user2661923 While your comment is mathematically correct, under the stated conditions the derivative need not be continuous (or even locally bounded) at $\alpha$. (That is, the question title reflects an "XY problem".)

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Nice comment.  I totally overlooked that.